# Error when Initializing Net Spell dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, filenotfoundexception, spell-checking

I am trying to check if a variable (Password) is in the English dictionary. When trying to use NetSpell dictionary check, I keep getting an error when trying to Initialize it. The error is a FileNotFoundException:
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\en-US.dic'.

**[Screenshot of Error message - Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\en-US.dic'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWSaf.png**)

Comment: Is the file in that location?

Comment: No, do I need to download en-US.dic? I installed the NetSpell package to Visual studio, that should have downloaded everything I need?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Copied the en-US.dic file from the library to where it was looking for it: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\en-US.dic.